# Webdeploy skip rule includes .css files as well as .cs

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy, skip

I am trying to use webdeploy in my build system. I would like it to be able to pull content files from my source code file but skip the code files. I am using a skip rule:

"-skip:objectName=filePath,absolutePath=.*.cs$"

but it skips .css files as well as .cs files. 
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your CSS files are in your package to begin with? Remember that, by default, Visual Studio only packages/deploys files that are:

1. Included in the `*proj` file
2. Marked with a `Build Action` of `Content`

You can change this behavior in `Project Properties -> Package/Publish Web -> Items to deploy`

Answer (score 0):

The regex is incorrect. This worked for me.

```
.*\.cs$
```